# gs:// s3:// http:// equivalent

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I see URIs for google cloud storage with the gs:// scheme and URIs for aws S3 with the s3:// scheme. How are these schemes translated into http and what do they mean?

How do these schemes know which region to point to and how are they expanded into full http bucket names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gs://` is a way of referencing a particular GCS object used by the `gsutil` command-line utility and a small number of Google Cloud APIs to reference GCS objects. For example, a Cloud Vision API request might have a section like this:

```
   "source":{
      "imageUri": "gs://bucket_name/path_to_image_object"
    }
```

Or a `gsutil` command might look like this:

```
$> gsutil cp resume.pdf gs://my_bucket/
```

There is no single mapping between `gs://` and `https://`. It is simply a way to specify a particular GCS object. An example HTTP mapping from a `gs://` URI might be something like `https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket_name/object_name`.

Answer (score 3):

### Transparent or Opaque Identifiers

The URIs are just identifiers that can be understood only by the respective Cloud service providers (like Google and Amazon here).

The URIs could either be transparent (i.e. directly have the region name and other location details as part of the URI) or it might be opaque (i.e. not part of the URI) and the service internally has a lookup table of some sort to map each bucket name to the location where the data is stored.

Since the only way to access the content at these URIs is using the respective Cloud providers, you need not have to worry about that detail and instead care only about how/when to use that content.

### APIs

If you need to know more information about a particular bucket hosted at any of these Cloud providers, you can use their APIs (and/or tools/libraries) to access the metadata about the bucket. This will also have a lot of metadata that you're looking for.

### Analogy to email addresses

Think of this as your email address provided by your email service provider. The email address acts as a unique identifier to identify your account. The data (i.e. emails, contacts) corresponding to an email account might not be stored in one particular region. The service provider has the freedom to decide how they wish to store/shard the data for different email addresses. They could also be replicating the data at more than one region/country/continent for both higher availability as for redundancy. All these details can also change over time if they wish to redesign, but still remain transparent to you since you only access the account using the email address. Same is true with Cloud Storage providers as well.

Comment: This is a good informative answer, but in I DO want to know how these things are expanded. I'm unsure of how these URIs deal with HTTP and HTTPS and my weak google-fu has been unable to help me find the documentation for how these URIs are translated, dealt with.

The usage scenario is I'm setting up some proxy access and need to know the specifics of the HTTP/HTTPS URL expansion and mechanics and the documentation on this seems scarce.

Comment: I think Brandon's answer details gives an example of how a `gs://` URI for a blob maps to a HTTPS URL to get the blob from Google Cloud Storage. In addition, there is some info here regarding [the steps you need to take care of when accessing through a proxy](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/faq#proxy-server).